# Reducing a CRC32 value to 16 or 8 bit

Tags: crc

In a message framing scheme I want to secure packets with a CRC error detection. Those packets are sent over TCP connection.

For small packets with a length smaller than 16 bytes, I'd choose CRC8. For packets smaller than 4096 bytes a CRC16 algorithm. For larger packets the CRC32 algorithm.

The most attractive CRC implementation currently is the CRC32C because of hardware support (at least on some Intel CPUs). But there are no special instructions for 8bit and 16bit CRCs.

My question is now: is it possible to reduce the 32Bit value of the CRC32C algorithm to a 16 or 8 bit value, without hurting the error detection performance in comparison to native CRC16 or CRC8 algorithms?

An example:

```
char buffer[256];
...
uint32_t crc32 = compute_crc32c_of_block( buffer, 256 );
uint16_t fake_crc16 = ( crc32 >> 16 ) ^ crc32;
uint8_t fake_crc8 = ( fake_crc16 >> 8 ) ^ fake_crc16;
```

Is fake_crc8 as good as a real CRC8 implementation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting question. I just wonder, does reducing payload size by 3 bytes really have any return on investment? Taking into account runtime impact of handling special cases (I assume you will have different struct definitions), byte alignment instead of dword alignment, etc.?

Comment: Yes, packets are byte-aligned but internal offsets of members are aligned to the requirements of the respective data type. With header compression some (mostly signaling) packets may shrink as small as 2 bytes, using an additional 4-byte check value for these seems a little excessive. The protocol should impose minimal framing overhead for usage on slow mobile connections i.e. GSM where all bandwidth should be given for actual payload.

Answer (score 5):

The low 8 bits of a 32-bit CRC will not have as good error-correcting properties as an 8-bit CRC, e.g. the assurance of detecting burst errors.  However it may be good enough for your application, depending the characteristics of the noise source.  If you have a good number of bit errors with correlation in their location, then you should use a real CRC.  If you have either rare bit flips or lots of gross errors, then a portion of a CRC would likely work just as well.

There is no substitute for testing to see how they perform.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of just using the lower 8/16 bits. This may perform as well or even better than reducing by XOR-folding. Normally there shouldn't be any errors because faulty data should be catched by TCP/IP or link-layer error detection before reaching the application level protocol. However in a critical medical context/usecase I can not rely on the TCP stack for data integrity, so a CRC seems a good tool for detecting transfer errors at the last receiving stage.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean with reducing by XOR-folding?

Comment: @mhanuel XOR-folding seems pretty obvious.  `d8 = (d16 >> 8) ^ (d16 & 0xff)` and the question provides an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you can specify the polynomial in the hardware CRC then padding it with zeros for bits that you don't want will result in a CRC that also has zeros at those bit positions. Then you simply discard them.

Using default data from the calculator `0x31 0x32 0x33 0x34 0x35 0x36 0x37 0x38 0x39` http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html) initial value 0x0, final xor 0x0 - here is the example

- CRC8 with **0x7** poly is `0xF4`
- CRC16 with **0x7**00 poly is `0xF400`
- CRC32 with **0x07**000000 is `0xF4000000`

Now, the problem is that the hardware may not support this kind of polynomial. For example hardware 16bit SPI hardware CRC calculator in STM32 processors only supports odd polynomials. 0xF4 is odd, but 0xF400 is even and it seemed to produce garbage.

Comment: My query bringing me here is can I map a CRC16/CRC32 (from a hardware module) to a CRC8 (via some transform) that is predefined by a protocol.  Some hardware CRC modules do not allow you to load the polynomial (as it is more efficient to use fixed polynomials).  But a helpful observation, nonetheless.

Comment: It would probably have to be some specially crafted 16 bit polynomial to begin with.